# create the regex to match whatever fields in Nagios

Tags: android, json, html-parsing, nagios

Im newbie in Nagios.. How to create HTML parsing Nagios raw data using Regex in Android? It is takes from nagios status.dat or status.cgi? can anyone help or give any suggestions..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (Java HTML Parser) for easy HTML parsing i.e.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of images
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements img = doc.select("img");
for (Element el : img)
{
    String imageUrl = el.attr("src");
    images.add(imageUrl);
}
```